# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer black screen

Tags: ios, swift2

hello i had a working code with `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.. it's a part barcode reader:

```
let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
        session.addInput(input)
        print("input done..")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

    let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    output.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    session.addOutput(output)
    output.metadataObjectTypes = output.availableMetadataObjectTypes

    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session) as AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.highlightView)
    session.startRunning()
```

It was starting and running also, there wasn't any error messeage and i used on my old iPhone too and i could see the picture of the camera. But 2 days ago my iphone's been replaced, i didn't change anything in the code. Now the app starting but i can see only black screen.

Does anybody know what could cause this?

Thank you!

Comment: Check premissions, in Settings>Privacy->Camera and make sure your app is enabled to access camera

Comment: no it's not enabled.. but how can i get access to use the camera? this is the same code.. my old device didn't ask me neither to enable acces to the camera.

Comment: so there isn't a popup where i could enable.

Comment: What version of iOS you were using , below iOS 8 it was not requried

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 8 you need to ask for the permission, you can do something like this

```
if ([AVCaptureDevice respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessForMediaType: completionHandler:)]) {
    [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {

        if (granted) {
            // Got the permission
        } else {
            // Permission has been denied.
        }
    }];
} else {
    // below ios 6
}
```

you can execute permission method in swifth

```
if AVCaptureDevice.respondsToSelector(Selector("requestAccessForMediaType"))
{
     AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: { (grandted:Bool) -> Void in
             //Check if granted and if its true do camera work else permission denied   
     })
 }
else
{
// Below iOS 6
}
```

Comment: sure, but on my other device why was it's working? it is ios9 beta. i didn't change anything in the code.

Comment: Your other devices was running iOS9 beta ? If that's the case then you have to ask for permission,

Comment: @solarenqu  Is it possible that you had just forgotten that you had let your App access the camera on the previous device?

Comment: yes my other devide was running iOS9 too.. and with that device i could see the camera screen..

Comment: By executing your code it should appear a popup and without saying yes you can't use camera, if you enable on settings again it will work again, if you disable once via setting or not allow it while pop up occur, you have to get permission again and you can do that by above code....

Comment: maybe i forget.. i donn't know.. but how can i allow if there isn't any popup where i could enable it on this new device? :) if i didn't change anything in the code it should apear i think, and then i could enable it.. but it's not showing up.. :(

Comment: Most probably you should get popup in this case, but its better you can ask for permission, so if you user disable it from setting it will ask again.

Comment: but if i check in settings, i can see apps that could use camera... but my app isn't there.. so i can't turn it on or off.. :( and popup not appear when i lunch the app.. :)

Comment: yes i think so, i should get popup but i didn't get :) but there is only black screen..

Comment: it must be a serious bug, because sometimes with the black screen it found a barcode.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used to test this out:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var session = AVCaptureSession.new()
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium

    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    let input = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: nil) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
    session.addInput(input)
    print("input done..")

    var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session) as AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    session.startRunning()
}
```

I appears that the problem was that you did not pass in the `NSError` required by the `AVCaptureDeviceInput`.  Xcode was not sure what the `try` statement was trying to do as well.  I've simply passed in `nil` into the constructor for now, but you *will* want to make sure that you handle it.  I also removed the part on setting up the output, as that was not relevant to my testing.  Feel free to add that back in.

I tested this on my iPhone 4 running iOS 7.1 for reference.

Comment: Cannot find an initializer for type 'AVCaptureDeviceInput' that accepts an argument list of type '(device: AVCaptureDevice!, error: nil)'

this is the first error.. :)

Comment: @solarenqu  You have AVFoundation.framework added to your project right?  Along with an `import AVFoundation` at the top of you code?

Comment: Hmm, odd that this broke from Swift 1.2 to 2...  It's odd that @C_X's solution doesn't work.